# Module not found error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js, this is my first node application so, please excuse me if I'm asking obvious question. I have a file called `utils.js` and I need to have functions defined in that file to be available in `main.js`. So I tried giving

`require(utils.js)`

But it is throwing me this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'utils.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
```

My `main.js` is under `c:\demo\proj\src\main\main.js` and `utils.js` is under `c:\demo\proj\src\utils\utils.js`.

I tried below require combinations, but still I am getting cannot find module error:

- `require(/proj/src/utils/utils.js`);
- `require(/utils.js`);
- `require(c:/demo/proj/src/utils/utils.js`);

Even I tried to put it under `node_modules` folder, but still same error. Can you kindly guide me what I am doing mistake here?

**Edit:**

I tried putting changing my folder structure as pointed out by @mithunsatheesh as below:

- project

  - src

    - utils - utils.js
- main.js

My `require` is as follows: `require('./src/utils/utils.js')`

But when I execute `node main.js` still I am getting below error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './src/utils/utils.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: Did you try `require('./utils');` ?

Comment: @limelights, yes I tried but still getting same error. I tried to put utils.js in the same location as main.js but no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

according to the folder structure you mentioned in the question, you have to try

```
require('../utils/utils.js')
```

This is the case if you have your project folder structured like

- proj

  - src

    - utils

      - utils.js
    - main

      - main.js

and you are doing `node main.js`

To comment on the details provided in your question.

1. please dont use `require(c:/demo/proj/src/utils/utils.js);` as you are tried out. imagine like you are exporting the `proj` folder with your project files then the mentioned require will be an error.
2. Also the folder structure could be made to something like

   - proj

     - src

       - utils
               - utils.js
     - main.js
     - package.json

so that you keep the main file in root of project folder. and require the utils.js like

```
 require('./src/utils/utils.js')
```

#### UPDATE

As far as ican see from the updated error message. Its still the issue with the path of 'utils.js' in require. From your updated folder structre It seems that `main.js` is in same level as `proj` folder, see that the proposed folder structure had `main.js` and `src` folder in same level inside `proj` folder.

Even that was a suggestion that I made as you were following a folder structure that dint make any sense. Simply `require('../utils/utils.js')` would have solved your issue without even altering the folder structure you mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: @PradeepSimha if you have tried out the steps that Minko Gechev and me pointed out, i believe the error that you get in console should not be `cannot find module utils.js` . So consider updating your question with the exact errors and the exact code you are using now.

Comment: I don't know how this is the answer because I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963845/export-default-results-in-module-not-found

Answer (score 4):

Use: `require('./utils.js');`. This is the correct way to require a module from a file which is located in required module's folder.

You must provide a relative or absolute path I guess `utils.js` is not in your root so `require('/utils.js');` is not the right path.

**Example:**

Imagine you have two files `utils.js` and `main.js` in the same folder. The content of `utils.js` is:

**utils.js**

```
exports.foo = function () {
    console.log('foo');
};
```

In order to call `foo` from `utils.js` in `main.js` you should use:

**main.js**

```
require('./utils.js').foo();
```

Comment: Did you mean, I should put it under node_modules folder?

Comment: @PradeepSimha : no it should be in same level as your main.js - which i guess is the node.js file you are running

Comment: Thanks and I tried same, I put both main.js and utils.js in same folder, still I am getting same error :(

Comment: Do you use the same require parameter `./utils.js` notice that I have `.` before the slash it's very important!

Comment: I have tried like this `var s = require('./utils.js').Foo();` both utils.js and main.js are in same folder now.

Comment: The name of the function is `foo` not `Foo` use it lower case.

Comment: I gave an example as Foo thats it, but I am calling correct function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your current folder. Are you in the right folder?

if(yes)
then this answer is not for you can leave and go further

if(not sure || No)

```
cd "your folder name." 
node "your file name.js."
```

Comment: you should better format the answer and use some Markdown formatting like `code` **bold** etc. - use Help/Preview button.