# I am new to nodejs and i keep getting this error

Tags: node.js, path, export, node-modules, throw

I keep getting this error. I have deleted node.js twice and reinstalled again. The same error keeps popping up. [error gotten from nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo13A.png)

This below is my person.js file which I was trying to export to the index.js file:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    greeting() {
        console.log(`my name is ${this.name}`)
    }
}

module.exports = Person;
```

This is the index.js file:

```
const Person = require("./person")

const person1 = new Person ("Philippa", 30)

person1.greeting()
```

Also, I tried doing this and i kept getting the same error:

```
const path = require("path")

console.log(__filename)

console.log(__dirname)
```

**RECENT EDIT:** I tried bringing in the path and fs modules since that's what I am working with for now using require(). Still getting this error below:

```
enter code here
$ node path.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\9470M\Documents\node_crash_course\path.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163176/module-not-found-error-in-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added whitespace to the file `person .js`. Rename it to `person.js`

Comment: I wish I could use an emoji right now. I have been trying to figure it out for two days now. Thank you.

Comment: The answer just solved one part of the issue as I cannot bring in the path and fs modules since that's what I am working with for  now

Comment: [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) are both included in node.js. you only need to require them as you did: `const path = require("path")`. check the linked documentation for using their API